# Ubuntu OpenLDAP and Mac OS X Roaming Profiles

Tags: openldap, roaming-profile

Today, I'm installing OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 11.04.  I have gone through the installation before a few times, but what I have never been able to do is use Mac OSX Lion's Directory Utility to administer the LDAP server, and also never got roaming profiles working.

SO the question is:

1) Is there a configuration I need in OpenLDAP so I can administer it remotely.  I vaguely remember something like that, but I can't find the answer online.

2) What do I need to setup roaming profiles for a mac os x.  I'd like to backup all my laptop data to the LDAP's machine, and potentially, also backup with time machine to an external HD mounted no the Ubutnu machine (but that's a few days ahead of time for now).

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of search, and trial and error, I found a tutorial that explained a step by step process for OS X 10.7.2, which also worked for Mountain Lion.  The problem was the mapping.  I had the correct SASL mechanisms saved to the plist, but I had to choose the RFC (Unix) mapping, then enter the base search dc=example,dc=com

The tutorial can be found at: http://iwatts.blogspot.com/2012/01/osx-1072-openldap-authentication.html

But I know have more questions:

1) The ldapuser I login with has a home dir on the server, but on the Mac I can't access the Finder, thereby I can't launch any applications that aren't in the dock.  And I don't have a downloads folder.